# Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 says "Storage Space Running Out"...Help!

Tags: samsung, insufficient-memory, storage

My Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, says: *Storage Space Running Out; Some Functions May Not Work*.
I purchased a 32 GB SDHC card to see if it would help.  I just opened up the SD card and inserted it. It did not Help. Was that wrong? Can somebody please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Insufficient storage does not necessarily imply insufficient storage on an external SD. Try going through our [tag:insufficient-memory] tag wiki, that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Your tablet is probably saving all your apps and files to your internal storage. You can start saving apps to your SD card or move all your large files onto your SD card manually.

[**Setting your apps to download to your SD card**](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1772970/set-default-download-location-card.html)

1. Open the `My Files` app
2. Navigate to your `SD card`, and create a folder called `Apps`
3. Tap on the icon with f`our horizontal lines` on the top right
4. Tap `Settings`
5. Under *Select Directories*, tap `Set Home Directory`
6. Select the `Apps` folder you just created on your SD card

Your tablet will now save apps to your SD card in the future.

You can also create more folders on your SD card and move all the bulky files (music, videos etc) that are on your internal storage to your SD card. You will have to do this manually.

Comment: Which Android version is this answer applicable for. Note that stock Android does not have a My files app. Also, that is not the procedure for moving apps to SD